# Query builder like Drupal's Database API?

Tags: php, drupal

I'm looking to branch out of plain mysql and mysqli and try to use something way better for database access thats not a DAO layer (adds too much complexity here).

When I did some Drupal development I had to use its Database API. It was really nice most of the time, allowing you to build queries and have it escape everything for you. PDO and mysqli prepared statements don't come close to the niceness and cleanliness of the Drupal Database API. And I still can't figure out how to, for example, use a prepared statement in mysqli to insert an unknown size of rows without building the query yourself, defeating the purpose of prepared statements. Its just getting in my way

Example from actual code of Drupal API

```
$query = db_select('tcsync_queue', 'q')
    ->condition('q.id', $post["tcsync_lastrecord"], '>')
    ->fields('q', array('id', 'uid', 'type', 'name', 'data'))
    ->execute();

foreach ($query as $item) {
    $updateitem = array(
        "id" => $item->id, 
        "uid" => $item->uid, 
        "type" => $item->type, 
        "name" => strtoupper($item->name),
        "data" => $item->data);
    ....
}
```

Is there a query builder that accomplishes some close to Drupal's query builder?

Comment: Are you looking for a standalone database framework or an alternative to Drupal?

Comment: Have you tried extracting Drupal's database class from the system and using it standalone? I'd imagine it'd be fairly straightforward to do with Drupal 7's version.

Comment: @Stian I'm looking for a standalone framework to use on my own non-drupal projects

Comment: @ceejayoz I admit I haven't tried but I'd imagine it would be quite difficult and be heavily integrated into Drupal core. I've never been good at decoding other PHP code and Drupal seems like a steep first try.

Comment: From what I recall of Drupal's database classes they're pretty well separated in D7. You'd likely have to include a few helper functions but it'd be well worth a try if you like the way they handle things

Comment: I'm working on something like this. Still not close to done, but it will be highly inspired by Drupal syntax. $obj->fields(array('COUNT(*)'))->limit(1, 2)->condition('user', $user, '=')->execute(); https://github.com/xqus/xQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the [NotORM<sup>*­Homepage*</sup>](http://www.notorm.com/) PHP library. It's quite lightweight (which I think is what you ask for) and a stand-alone component so you don't have the burden with integration so much.

It works with PDO as the connection object:

```
include "NotORM.php";
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=software");
$db = new NotORM($pdo);
```

so it supports any database that is available in PDO.

You can then just run queries in an easy fashion, this is an example for a database with an application table:

```
foreach ($db->application() as $application) { // get all applications
    echo "$application[title]\n"; // print application title
}
```

When it comes to where and limits, it works like this:

```
$applications = $db->application()
    ->select("id, title")
    ->where("web LIKE ?", "http://%")
    ->order("title")
    ->limit(10)
;
foreach ($applications as $id => $application) {
    echo "$application[title]\n";
}
```

It does things well, which is not the case with similar looking code, for example the sql code in codeigniter.

Comment: Wow, thats almost exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for pointing this out, I just have to choose between this and CI

Comment: I wouldn't consider CI an alternative to this actually. Next to that I would not consider to use CI for anything, there are always much better solutions than CI.

Comment: Its more of I'm trying to find some kind of framework to give structure to my site (MVC?) since its just lots of handwritten code now. But thats a separate question

Comment: You can look for a framework for that, symfony2 is a quite good one in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd like the Doctrine 2's DBAL.
I'll throw some saple code for you:

```
    $locationIds = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);

    $locationTreeDepthQb = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
    $locationTreeDepthQb->select("COUNT(*) as count")
        ->from('location_tree_data', 'd')
        ->where("d.tree_depth >= 2")
        ->andWhere("d.tree_id IN (?)");
    $stmt = $conn->executeQuery($locationTreeDepthQb->getSQL(), array($locationIds), array(Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY));
    $res = $stmt->fetch();
```

Please note how easy is to pass an array for a "IN" SQL statement in this query builder.

Documentation can be found here: 
http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.2/en/

Comment: That looks really rough, but seems workable. I'll take a look at it

Comment: Doctrine2 is very good, and they recently passed an external security audit.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter does this really well:

e.g.

Select:

```php
$this->db->select('title')->from('mytable')->where('id', $id)->limit(10, 20);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Insert:

```php
$this->db->set('title',$title)->insert('mytable');
```

Update:

```php
$this->db->where('id', $id)->set('title',$title)->update('mytable');
```

See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Wow, that looks really close to what I'm after. IIRC though, it was something you had to build your whole website with, kinda like a large MVC framework. Can you just use the DB API without having to move the entire app to code igniter?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/kenaniah/insight/blob/master/classes/query.php can be modified to stand on its own.